# When Flutter is run, the project does not appear on the emulator screen

Tags: flutter

When I press f5 and run flutter, the emulator opens, but the flutter project does not appear on the emulator screen, but when I select the edge screen, it opens on the edge screen. How can I solve this? Thank you.
[image]

I couldn't find anything about this on the internet

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you provided, it appears that the app is still building. Just leave it for a while and see if the build completes. If it does not, then try running flutter clean followed by flutter pub get, restart your VS Code, and try again. If that doesn't work, I'd recommend trying Android Studio to run your app on the emulator. Also try updating flutter to its latest version using flutter upgrade. hope this helps :)

Comment: It didn't work, I think I'm getting some kind of gradel error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it takes time when you run it for the first time.. Depending upon your Laptops\PCs performance can take upto several minutes.

1. You can try changing SDK version of the virtual Device
2. use RUN without Debugging